# Threshold function for a graph not being planar

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, planar-graphs

A graph property $\mathcal{P}$ is monotone increasing if $G\in \mathcal{P}$ implies $G+e \in \mathcal{P}$, i.e., adding an edge to a graph does not destroy the property.

It is well-known that every monotone increasing graph property has a threshold $t(n)$, i.e,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }P(G_{n,p}~has~property~\mathcal{P})=0$$ if $p<<t(n)$ and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }P(G_{n,p}~has~property~\mathcal{P})=1$$ if $p>>t(n)$. Here $G_{n,p}$ is a random graph with $n$ vertices where each edge in the graph is added independently with
probability $p$.

Property of a graph **NOT being planar** is monotone increasing. So the first question is what the threshold $t(n)$ for such a property $\mathcal{P}$ is. Does anyone know such a result?

There is another model for random graph, say $G_{n,m}$, which describes a random graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Similarly we can define a threshold $t^*(n)$ for a given property $\mathcal{P}$ concerning this model, i.e.,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }P(G_{n,m}~has~property~\mathcal{P})=0$$ if $m<<t^*(n)$ and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }P(G_{n,m}~has~property~\mathcal{P})=1$$ if $m>>t^*(n)$.

It is well-known that if $m\geq 3n-5$, then $G_{n,m}$ is not planar and thus $G_{n,m}$ has propery $\mathcal{P}$. However, is there any result for the exact value of $t^*(n)$?

Answer (score 9):

In the Erdős–Rényi model, the threshold for the planarity is know to be $t(n) = 1/n$. Perhaps one of the easiest ways to see this is the following.

If $p=o(1/n)$, then a straightforward union bound implies that the expected number of cycles in $G(n,p)$ is
$$
\sum_{k=3}^n \binom{n}{k}\cdot \frac{(k-1)!}{2} \cdot p^k < \sum_{k=3}^n (pn)^k = \frac{(pn)^3}{1-pn} \to 0.
$$
So, $G(n,p)$ has no cycles with high probability, and thus it is planar.

On the other hand, if $p=\omega(1/n)$, then one can easily check (again, via a straightforward union bound) that
$$P\big(\alpha(G(n,p))> n/7\big) \le \binom{n}{n/7} \cdot (1-p)^{\binom{n/7}{2}}< 2^ne^{-pn^2/100} \to 0.$$
Thus, $\chi(G(n,p)) \ge n/\alpha(G(n,p)) \ge 7$ with high probability. In particular, this implies that $G(n,p)$ is not planar.

Try to check out some classic books on the topic (e.g. Béla Bollobás, *Random Graphs*, which has already been mentioned by Brendan McKay) if you want to investigate some stronger properties like *sharp thresholds*.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the model where a random graph is made by adding one edge at a time chosen uniformly at random from edges not yet present.

Łuczak, Pittel and Wierman (1994) showed that there is a function $f(c)$ such that when the number of edges is $\frac12 n +cn^{2/3}$ the probability of being nonplanar tends to $f(c)$. Also $f(-\infty)=0$ and $f(\infty)=1$.

I got this from Béla Bollobás, *Random Graphs*, p151.  His reference is "The structure of a random graph near the point of the phase transition", Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 341, 721-748.

Comment: An interesting subsequent article is https://dmtcs.episciences.org/2343 of Noy, Ravelomanana and Rué, where they obtain an exact expression for the function $f$.